# How do i check if 2 Lists have the same Sprites in c#

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

the question is, how do i compare two lists of the same type(in this case Sprite) and check if they are equal. 
To get into my code, i have GameObjects symbol, shadow and cable and those change their sprite with a buttonclick(different script). On the other hand i have GameObject[] and i already have GameObjects inserted. Now i make a Dictionary with GameObject as key and a specific List of Sprites as value, i search for a key and return the value into List ActualList and compare that with a List composed  of the current sprites of GameObjects symbol, shadow, cable.
My Problem is tho that its not applying RigidBody to the GameObject, so the if statement seems to not work. Is there maybe a different way to compare two lists.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;
public class Rigi : MonoBehaviour
{
    public GameObject[] Akkus;
    public Button Generator;
    public GameObject symbol, shadow, cable;
    int count1;
    public Sprite[] spriteSymbols, spriteShadows, spriteCables;
    public Dictionary<GameObject, List<Sprite>> AkkuDic = new 
Dictionary<GameObject, List<Sprite>>();
    public List<Sprite> ActualList = new List<Sprite>();
    public void On_Click_Button1()
    {

        List<Sprite> CompareList = new List<Sprite>();
        CompareList.Add(symbol.GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>().sprite);
        CompareList.Add(shadow.GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>().sprite);
        CompareList.Add(cable.GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>().sprite);

        AkkuDic.TryGetValue(Akkus[count1], out ActualList);

        if(ActualList.SequenceEqual(CompareList))
        {
            Rigidbody RigidbodyGameobject = 
Akkus[count1].AddComponent<Rigidbody>();

        }
    }

    public void Awake()
    {
        List<Sprite> mySpritesWind = new List<Sprite>();
        mySpritesWind.Add(spriteSymbols[5]);
        mySpritesWind.Add(spriteShadows[0]);
        mySpritesWind.Add(spriteCables[0]);
        List<Sprite> mySpritesOel = new List<Sprite>();
        mySpritesOel.Add(spriteSymbols[4]);
        mySpritesOel.Add(spriteShadows[2]);
        mySpritesOel.Add(spriteCables[1]);
        List<Sprite> mySpritesWasser = new List<Sprite>();
        mySpritesWind.Add(spriteSymbols[5]);
        mySpritesWind.Add(spriteShadows[0]);
        mySpritesWind.Add(spriteCables[0]);
        List<Sprite> mySpritesSolar = new List<Sprite>();
        mySpritesWind.Add(spriteSymbols[3]);
        mySpritesWind.Add(spriteShadows[5]);
        mySpritesWind.Add(spriteCables[0]);
        List<Sprite> mySpritesKern = new List<Sprite>();
        mySpritesWind.Add(spriteSymbols[1]);
        mySpritesWind.Add(spriteShadows[1]);
        mySpritesWind.Add(spriteCables[1]);
        List<Sprite> mySpritesKohle = new List<Sprite>();
        mySpritesWind.Add(spriteSymbols[2]);
        mySpritesWind.Add(spriteShadows[4]);
        mySpritesWind.Add(spriteCables[1]);

        AkkuDic.Add(Akkus[0], mySpritesWind);
        AkkuDic.Add(Akkus[1], mySpritesOel);
        AkkuDic.Add(Akkus[2], mySpritesWasser);
        AkkuDic.Add(Akkus[3], mySpritesSolar);
        AkkuDic.Add(Akkus[4], mySpritesKern);
        AkkuDic.Add(Akkus[5], mySpritesKohle);

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The default comparer used in SequenceEqual will check to see if the reference pointer of the class instance of Sprite in CompareList is the same "memory reference pointer" as is stored in ActualList. Without seeing the full lifecycle of this we cannot be sure, but if the GetComponent() ever creates a new instance of the class Sprite your code will not work as expected. If I remember Unity, it may well create a new instance or return a cached instance.

I expect you need to compare some property (like AssetID or other unique value of the sprite) between the lists, no the list reference pointers themselves; especially if you are not in complete control of the Sprite class life history within the application and you are using someone elses Factory (i.e. GetComponent)

Comment: So should i add AssetID´s to my Lists in the Dictionary, is there a way to convert a .GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>().sprite to an AssetID, so i can compare them to those, because if that works this may very well be the answer

Comment: I think Unity has an GetInstanceID() function that gets the unique object reference (https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Object.GetInstanceID.html).